# Assignment of variable within if-statement

Tags: if-statement, variable-assignment, modelica

When I try to assign a variable x within the body of an if-statement I get unexpected results if the variable also occurs in the condition of the if-statement.

For example, the code

```
model algorithmTest_25p05p2021


Real x(start=0);
Real y(start=0);

algorithm 

y := sin(time);
x := sin(time); 

if x < 0 then // replace with y < 0 --> x is correctly truncated
  x := 0;
end if;


end algorithmTest_25p05p2021;
```

results in
[image]

I used OMEdit in OpenModelica 1.17.0, simulation time 120s, maximum step time of 1s.
I can't wrap my head around what is going on here.

In my understanding, the algorithm section implies that x is initialized to its start value 0. After initialization, I thought the statements in the algorithm section are executed in order. So, before the if-statement, x is set to the value of x=sin(time).
Afterwards, I expected that the if-statement would set x=0 if sin(time) < 0 and leave x to be x=sin(time) if sin(time)>=0.

You see what happens instead: x stays zero after the condition triggers for the first time.

What confuses me even more is that replacing the "x<0"-condition with a "y<0"-condition fixes the issue.

What have I missed here? Any pointers to the Modelica specification?

EDIT (27.05.2021):
As this behaviour appears to be a bug in OpenModelica 1.17.0, I posted it on their Github, see
https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/7484

Comment: It could be a bug. Note that algorithms in Modelica are weird, relations trigger events, so x < 0 triggers an event. You can do noEvent(x < 0) which does seem to generate the correct behavior if you want x to look like the positive part of sin.

Comment: Yes, I want x to look like the positive part of sin. "noEvent(x<0)" indeed works in OpenModelica 1.17.0, however I struggle to understand what's happening in detail. If I replace "x<0" with "y<0" in above example, events are triggered and I obtain the desired behaviour. So I suspect it has sth to do with x appearing both in the condition as well as in the body of the if-statement.

Comment: Am I understanding the plot correctly? Does the value of `x` switch back to the correct value at t=120s? A strong indication for a bug in my understanding. Seems the event that ends the simulation "fixes" the issue there...

Comment: @MarkusA. : yes, you're understanding the plot correctly. Interestingly, whether the event  that ends the simulation causes x to jump on its correct value depends on the simulation time I choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be a bug.

Clearly there should be an event for `x<0`, but the event-logic is only important when `x` is close to zero and thus should have a minimal impact on graph.

The relevant sections of the specification I can find are:

- If-statements are only evaluated if true
  https://specification.modelica.org/maint/3.5/statements-and-algorithm-sections.html#if-statement
- If the condition and the hidden state is inconsistent an event is generated:
  https://specification.modelica.org/maint/3.5/equations.html#events-and-synchronization
- Conceptually `x` is initialized with its start-value, but it doesn't matter since it is unconditionally assigned https://specification.modelica.org/maint/3.5/statements-and-algorithm-sections.html#execution-of-an-algorithm-in-a-model

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you have an idea what would be good coding practise to circumvent this bug? To assign a value to a variable dependent on the value of the variable itself is a common algorithmic task. I assume I could always work with dummy variables like y in the example. Also do you happen to know whether other Modelica environments (e.g. Dymola) show the same behaviour?

Comment: Dymola doesn't show this behavior, and I hope no other tools do. I don't know how circumvent it.

Comment: Here is what I would code for this situation that would replace the whole if-statement: `x:=max(x,0)`